# Examining growth rates and sex differences

Tags: r, group-differences, growth-model

I'm trying to figure out the best statistical test to use to understand my data. I've searched but haven't found anything super applicable. I'm working with an endangered animal species and have a lot of measurements taken at the same time each year, and I'm trying to study growth. I'd like to know two main things: when this species reaches adult size (so stops growing), and whether there are differences between male and females at any ages. So basically trying to see if there's a significant difference between (for example) weight at age 4 and at age 5; if there's no difference, that should mean they stop growing at age 4.

I'll be doing the same test for lots of different measurements, e.g., weight, spine length, arm length, etc. I have repeat measures for some animals because some were measured at various ages (for example I have Zoe's weight at ages 1 and 2 years), but some animals were only measured once, so that has to be controlled for I'm sure. I don't have tons of data because this species is pretty endangered and has a low population size--usually around 5-12 measurements for each age group.

I've tried a bunch of things, but have been told by various people that they don't really work. In the beginning I was just comparing the means at each age (so a t test to compare the weight for males at age 1 vs their weight at age 2, etc., which is obviously too simplistic). I've tried mixed models, looking at marginal means of regressions, etc. but nothing seems to really be getting to the root of it. Especially because there is, for example, a significant difference between animal's weights between ages 3 and 5, but there's no difference between ages 3 and 4 or 4 and 5. So this means they are still growing, but if I just looked at the straight means, then they stop and start again.

I hope this was enough information to be helpful. Please let me know if you have any ideas! Below is my most recent attempt. I'm using R btw!

`mod<-mixed(Weight~Sex+Age+Sex*Age+(1|ID), data = data)`

`emmeans(mod, list(pairwise ~ Age|Sex), adjust = "tukey")`

Comment: Have you tried using ANOVA test to derive a p-value that determines whether there is a statistical difference between the mean of two groups using their variance?

Comment: I don't see why a t test is "obviously too simplistic". Why not use a t-test? This seems to be a pretty straightforward case of applying hypothesis testing (t-test, ANOVA etc.) a bunch of times to different combinations (comparing different ages, comparing genders). I think your low number of measurements per group is what will cause you problems (which is probably why you see the weird things like sig. diff. b/t 3 and 5 but not 3 to 4 or 4 to 5. Sample size too small, uncertainty too high). So maybe try doing 2 year gaps like that so that you can group some samples together.

Comment: I'll add that with samples so small, you might get very few p<0.05 values to begin with, so you might just have to "take a best guess" at what the age of stopping growth is. For example, if you get p<0.07 for diff. b/t age 3 and 4, p<0.08 b/t 4 and 5 and p<0.25 b/t all others, you might just have to "eyeball" it and say that it looks like the most likely point of no more growth is either 4 to 5 or 5 to 6, even though NONE of the measurements were statistically significantly different at the p < 0.05 level.

Comment: @JayEkosanmi it was originally suggested that I do mixed model ANOVAs, but one professor then said it wouldn't actually be appropriate to do those, although I can't recall his reasoning (I'm a grad student with not a ton of stats background if that explains my ineptitude!)

Comment: @VladimirBelik that would be my ignorance of statistics talking! However because there are so many levels it was explained to me that a regression might be best. I agree the low sample size is an issue for sure. Would t-tests be appropriate given that there are some repeat measures?

Comment: No worries at all! So if you did regression, could you explain what exactly your X and Y variables would be? Most critically, if you did regression, what would be the response variable? Additionally, could you explain what you mean by "given that there are some repeat measurements"?